# Receiving same output in if and else condition, how to resolve?

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf, c-strings, string-comparison

I am trying to execute below program but it give same output, in if else condition. In output I only get Working day only even I give value as sunday.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
char day; 
printf("Enter Day name: \n"); 
scanf("%c", &day);

if (day =="sunday"){
    printf("Holiday");
    }
    else{
        printf("Working day.");
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `day` is a `char`. It cannot hold several characters and the zero terminator. You can  compare it to other characters (`day == 'X'` or `day == '\0'`, ...) not to *strings*.

Comment: You need to study strings before using them. C doesn't have a string class. This code should give a fair amount of warnings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly compare strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Comment: You should get used to run your programs in a debugger. As soon as you try to check that `day` really contains `"sunday"` you should see some "surprising" content. And reading your compiler warnings should not be optional. They should also point to some error in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The program is invalid.

To enter a string you need to declare a character array instead of an object of the type `char` where the entered string will be stored. For example

```
char day[10];
printf("Enter Day name: \n"); 
scanf("%9s", day);
```

To compare strings you need to use standard function `strcmp` declared in the header `<string.h>`.

```
#include <string.h>

//...

if ( strcmp( day, "sunday" ) == 0 ){
    printf("Holiday\n");
    }
else{
        printf("Working day.\n");
    }
```